# Method for identifying .onion links in text?

Tags: python, regex, url, tor

how can I identify .onion links in a text bearing in mind they can come in a variety of way;

```
hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
http://hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
http://www.hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
```

I'm thinking of regex but `(.*?.onion)` would return the whole paragraph where the URL Link is buried in

Comment: Try `\S+\.onion\b`. However, if the link contain a space, this won't help.

Comment: You have to find anything that is always before the link and never appear inside the link. Like @WiktorStribiżew proposed, you can use whitespace characters for it.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew I tried that regex here https://regex101.com/r/5ArhNJ/2 it doesn't seem to catch it  at all

Comment: You just did not test properly. https://regex101.com/r/1xVHyo/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it: `(?:https?://)?(?:www)?(\S*?\.onion)\b` (Added non-capturing groups - credit: @WiktorStribiżew)

Demo:

```
s = '''hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
https://hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
http://www.hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
https://www.google.com
https://stackoverflow.com'''


for m in re.finditer(r'(?:https?://)?(?:www)?(\S*?\.onion)\b', s, re.M | re.IGNORECASE):
    print(m.group(0))
```

Output

```
hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
https://hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
http://www.hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion
```

Comment: You can use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`.
Also using `?` at the beginning is in this case useless and makes regex more complicated. `(http(s)?://)?(www)?([^\s]*?\.onion)` is equal to `\S*?\.onion`

Comment: @Szymon That would be to prevent false positives like `lol...imAn.onion`.

Comment: However, I do agree, `\S` is more concise than `^\s`.

Comment: it doesn't prevent false positives as `?` 0 or more which means it will also match `lol...imAn.onion`. Check https://regex101.com/r/xfIO3u/1

Comment: Easier to use `re.findall(r'(?:https?://)?(?:www)?\S*?\.onion', s)`

Comment: If you want to avoid false positives caused by multiple `.` in a row, you can use   `(?:[^\s\.]+?\.)+?onion`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. The non-capturing groups are a nice touch to filter out the fluff.

Comment: This will capture a non-onion link like: `http://www.onion.com` as `http://www.onion`

Comment: @user3191569 Thank you for accepting my answer. Please make sure to use a raw string and add a word boundary character to the end. Look at my edited answer for details. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy:

`([^\s]+\.onion)`

Matches all Characters starting from the first Space till ".onion".

Comment: 1. No need to enclose whole regex in `()` since it's already a group(0). 2. Instead of `[^\s]` use \S. 3. It will match `www.onion` from `www.onion.com`

Answer (score 0):

An approach without regex:

```
url = 'http://hfajlhfjkdsflkdsja.onion'
split = url.split('.onion')
if len(split)==2 && len(split[1])==0:
   %do something
```

Comment: How will this handle "Here is a link: blahblah.onion"? It'll split it into "Here is a link: blahblah".

Comment: it will split it in ['Here is a link: blahblak',' '] and you enter the if struct.

Comment: OP wants just the "blahblah" part though. Not the rest of it.

Comment: I read the question: how can I identify .onion links... -, I didn't realise the need to extract the blabla part

Comment: You can extract it: 'Here is a link: blahblak'.split()[-1] # 'blahblak'

Comment: True, but then you're better of with the nice regex constructed by @Coldspeed

Comment: Lol@ how blahblah become blahblak :-)